# Lift (Scala) form validation

Tags: forms, validation, scala, lift, mapper

I have a question for which I couldn't find an answer anywhere in the web. I have a lift-based web application written on Scala. There is a form in my application which is driven by a snippet. I use Mapper for my models, and I use `override def validations ...` to define model's validation parameters. The template code looks like this:

```
<form class="lift:GroupManager.addGroup?form=POST&action=add">
<div class="row collapse" style="width: 30em">
  <div class="small-8 columns">
    <span class="group-name prefix radius"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <span class="submit button small postfix radius">Add New Group</span>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
</form>
```

The snippet code:

```
def addGroup = {
  object groupName extends RequestVar[String]("")

  def doAddGroup() = {
    val group = Group.create.createdAt(new java.util.Date).groupName(groupName.is)
    group.validate match {
      case Nil => {
        group.save
        S.notice("Group '" + group.groupName.is + "' has been added successfully")
      }
      case errors:List[FieldError] => {
        S.error(errors)
      }
    }
  }

  ".group-name" #> SHtml.text(groupName.is, groupName(_), "id" -> "group-name") &
    ".submit" #> SHtml.submit("Add group", doAddGroup)
}
```

The model's validations override:

```
object groupName extends MappedString(this, 700) {
  override def dbColumnName = "group_name"
  override def dbNotNull_? = true
  override def validations = valMinLen(1, S.?("Group name should not be empty!")) _ ::
    valMaxLen(700, S.?("Group name should not be more than 700 characters long!")) _ ::
    valUnique(S.?("Group name should be unique!")) _ ::
    super.validations
}
```

Now everything is perfect except the fact that when invalid data is provided, S.error is used to inform user about problems. What I want to do is to highlight the form element (by applying class="error") in which the data is invalid and add a `<span>` element with the error message in front of the form element. Is there a simple way to do that with Lift framework? Or I should just traverse through `errors:List[FieldError]` and fetch field information from that array, which does not seem too elegant to me?

Comment: This discussion may be of help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/4LCWldUaUVA

Comment: Thank you for this link, I've found some interesting ideas there. However, I am still unable to find out how to add "error" class to the original form element in case an error occurs, although now I can output the error message in front of it.